# Views 3: template suggestion file for header/footer parts?

Tags: views, theming

In Views 3, is there any type of template suggestion for header and footer parts of a view?

I know I can paste Full HTML into Global Header and Footer fields, but - as I have the main part themed in a tpl file - I'd also find it more comfortable to have the header/footer parts laid out in an external text file.

Comment: How can we get header and footer variables for view ? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273196/how-to-get-views-header-and-footer-in-view-block-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no template that I know about, but nothing can stop you from overriding the header and footer values in a view's general template like `views-view.tpl.php`, or even include a separate file instead of outputing the variable directly.