# How to get views header and footer in view block template

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I have created view as block and in block twig template i can print view fields as
content['#view'].field['field_machine_name'].value(row) 
HOw can i print text in textarea that i set as header and footer for this view.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display view header or footer in twig template, look at core [views-view.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21stable%21templates%21views%21views-view.html.twig/8.6.x) and all the available variables. In your case :

> header: The optional header.
>
> footer: The optional footer.

In your twig `views-view--[view-name].html.twig`, you can display your variable like this :

```
<p>{{ header }}</p>
```